# I want to display by category (brand) using angular, the backend part is tested with Postman and it works, I don't know what to do next

Tags: angular, typescript

In rolexComponent.ts

```
productsList: Product[]=[];
getAllProductByBrand(){
    this.productService.getAllProductByBrand('ROLEX').subscribe((data:any) =>{
      this.productsList = data;
    },
    err => console.error(err)
    )
  }
```

In productService.ts

```
getAllProductByBrand(brand:string){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url+'/category?'+brand);
  }
```

In backend controller

```
@GetMapping("/category")
    public List<Product> getAllProductByBrand(@RequestParam(name="brand", required = false) Brand brand){
        return productService.getAllProductByBrand(brand);
    }
```

thank you very much

Comment: Let me ask something about your question. what is your main problem ? Do you want to display productsList ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display that productsList data coming from getAllProductByBrand, it is simple . You can use *ngfor to display that list.

Example, productsList have the following array.(Your API's response value)

```
productsList = [{'brand':'rolex'}]
```

And then, you can get that category(brand) by adding the following code in your html file .

```
<div *ngFor = "let product of productsList">
  <span>{{product.brand}}</span>
</div>
```